# traerme una imagen de una api en flutter

Tags: api, flutter, imagen, http

Tengo el siguiente problema: necesito traerme una imagen almacenada en mi base de datos con un código similar a este 0187c6ca-e504-7385-b394-5e8c8f63c993, al yo pasarle este código en una petición de formato json y con método post en Postman me retorna una imagen en bytes.Necesito traérmela a mi aplicación en fluter de la misma manera que me la trae en Postman y mostrarla, el problema que tengo es que he intentado hacerlo con las dependencias http y getx y no doy con la tecla de como hacerlo ya que en todas las ocasiones o me da fallo o no hace la petición bien

---

```
  Future<void> _getImage() async {
    try {
      final response = await _getImageFromAPI();
      print(response.toString());
      if (response != null &&
          response.headers!['content-type'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        image = Image.memory(response.bodyBytes as Uint8List);
        Get.snackbar(
          'Imagen cargada',
          'La imagen se ha cargado correctamente',
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        );
        // Navegamos a una pantalla para mostrar la imagen
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
        'Error al cargar imagen',
        'Ha ocurrido un error al cargar la imagen',
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<Response<Uint8List>?> _getImageFromAPI() async {
    print("code: ${user.user!.profileImg}");

    final response = await GetConnect().post(
        'https://api-nutric.studio128k.com/api/documents/render',
        {'document': "0187c6ca-e5404-7385-b394-5e8c8f63c993"});
    print("respiuesta 1: ${response.body}");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final bytes = response.bodyBytes;
      print(bytes.toString());
      return Response(
          bodyBytes: bytes,
          statusCode: response.statusCode,
          headers: response.headers);
    } else {
      final bytes = response.body;
      print(bytes.toString());
      return Response(
          bodyBytes: bytes,
          statusCode: response.statusCode,
          headers: response.headers);
    }
  }
```

este seria el código que estoy usando ahora, pero no me retorna nada, por otro lado Postman si me devuelve la imagen

Comment: ¿Y el código? Agregar código que no esté en imágenes ayuda para resolver el problema.